# Secure telnet for POP3 and others

Tags: linux, fedora, ssl, telnet

I need a command to connect to POP3 server, set startTLS, and get secure connection. I neet something to use like telnet. Is there any program that can achieve it?

--edit
I'm just trying to write similar SMTP server, and I'd like to test in time handshake done by starttls. Is there something to help me?

Comment: If you are writing an SMTP server, it would only take a few minutes to knock up a client to interact with it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use [openssl](http://www.openssl.org/) to do this:

```
$ openssl s_client -crlf -connect mail.domain.com:110 -starttls pop3
```

This will initiate the session and get the certificate exchange going.  You'll see the certificate exchange messages going back and forth, then the standard pop3 prompt:

```
+OK Hello there.
user username
+OK Password required.
pass passw0rd
+OK logged in.
list
+OK
```

Comment: is there a way that client doesn't authenticate on start, but when I type starttls?

Comment: @oneat Not that I know of, can you add more detail to your question about what you are trying to achieve and it will help focus the answers better

Comment: usually ssl starts when starttls is supplied, but in your example it's supplied instantly (as I understand). I want to write starttls by myself to server and not to be written by opensll.

Comment: @oneat Yes, I understand that from your previous comment, it would be helpful if you could edit the question to add more detail about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score -1):

Isn't it easier to just set up whatever connects via POP3 to use SSL/TSL in the first place? Better use IMAP if you can, the protocol is much more robust and moreover efficient